# Accelerometer data integration (MMSE)

Tags: probability, integration, estimation

1. Based on the raw accelerometer measurements use simple integration on the raw $X$ and $Y$ axis data to determine the velocity and position.
2. If we assume a linear model $Y = aX + b$ for determine the MMSE of $X$ (where $X$ is acceleration along one of the $x$ or $y$ acceleration axes), how does it compare with the results in part 1?

The first part is relatively easy, but I am not sure about second part.